# How can I designate range within an column when making an awk file?

Tags: awk, array

I have this data file which I want to sort out by making an `awk` file. I want to find the average rate within certain range of ages. For example, from  `10<age<20`and `20<age<30`. And I can't find a way to calculate averages only for those people. How can I do this?

```
name rate hours age sex
AIDAN 3.5 19 22 M
AMELIA 5.25 16 13 F
NOAH 4.5 24 25 M
ISABELLA 4.25 17 15 F
LIAM 4.5 23 23 M
AVA 5.5 24 25 F
CAYDEN 6 21 28 M
```

Comment: your example has 0 persons with age between 10 and 20. :)

Answer (score 2):

select line with `$4 < 20 && $4 > 10`

```
awk 'BEGIN { c=0 ; s=0 ; }
     ($4 < 20) && ($4 > 10) { c++ ; s+=$2 ; }
     END { if (c>0 ) printf "average %.1f\n",s/c ;}' ...
```

with an error message if no lines are selected.

Comment: OP wants to find the average *rate*, so I believe that you should be adding `$2`.

Comment: to get all range, use int(ln(#4)/ln(10)) to get age range. ( no dollar in my tablet??)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand the question. 
Do you want to be able to get two results?

In case it's not obvious, [Archemar's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/274198/80216) can be extended to collect multiple statistics:

```
awk '($4 > 10) && ($4 < 20) { c10++; s10+=$2; }
     ($4 > 20) && ($4 < 30) { c20++; s20+=$2; }
     END { if (c10>0) print "average for 10-20:", s10/c10
           if (c20>0) print "average for 20-30:", s20/c20 }' …
```

- Of course it's good programming practice to initialize your variables. 
  But `awk` initializes variables to null,
  which acts like zero when used in mathematical contexts,
  so it's not really necessary.
- As Archemar pointed out, you can exercise some control
  over the output format (i.e., how the result is written) with `printf`. 
  But `awk`'s defaults (i.e., how it implements the `print` statement)
  are reasonable.
- As Archemar pointed out, you might want
  to issue an explicit error message when there are no people in a range
  (rather than just *not* reporting an average).

Answer (score 0):

awk '{if ($4>=10&&$4<=20) {X=X+1;Y=Y+$2}} END {print Y/X}' < infile